# .htaccess and ForceType question - extensionless files?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<Files .*>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>

<Files mytesting>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>

<Files *.asp>
ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

Is it possible using the ForceType directive to allow extensionless files, rather than doing selected extensions, e.g. the mytesting one above?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Use `<Files *>` to match any file.

If you want to match only files that do not have extensions, use `<Files [^.]+>`.